# Decorator vs. abstract factory vs. factory method

Tags: decorator, abstract-factory

Can anyone explain how can I distinguish between decorator, abstract factory and factory method patterns with real examples please. Precisely, I need to understand when I should use decorator and abstract factory and factory method.

Answer (score 0):

Design Patterns are not so easy to explain by just text. I'd advise you to watch this playlist of Derek Banas: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLF206E906175C7E07 
I learned the patterns from him, and I still remember his tutorials when programming. His examples were really clear to me, and they will to you.